# "libvw.so: file not recognized: File truncated" and "make -j 8"

Tags: makefile

I get the `libfoo.so: file not recognized: File truncated` error from `make -j 8`.
When I remove the file and re-make, everything works:

```
$ make clean
$ make -j 8
...
libvw.so: file not recognized: File truncated
make: *** [all] Error 2
$ mv libvw.so libvw.so-
$ make -j 8
success
$ cmp libvw.so libvw.so-
```

i.e., `libvw.so` was fine.

with `-j 8` it works right away:

```
$ make clean
$ make
success
```

So, how do I use `-j 8` with shared libraries?

(This project uses GNU Make, so a GNU-specific solution is fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're missing a dependency in one of your makefile rules and the error happens because libw.so is still being built at the time the executable tries to link to it.

But do note also that there are some versions of make out there that have bugs with dependencies in parallel. Make sure you're using a distro that patches this kind of thing.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem. But If it is a dependency problem how's that it successfully builds on second attempt? I'm using debian:latest docker image and I guess I'm not having a faulty Make version. However, how can I make sure if it is a bug with my make version?

Comment: @Farzan When parallel make encounters an error, it continues building all in-progress rules until they either complete or fail. Thus, the next time the failing rule is built, the file it needs is there.

Comment: @Farzan also note that most Docker images are horribly maintained, this is a huge security problem among other bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Are you suggesting that even official images (debian for example) on docker hub are not reliable enough to use in production?
Regarding parallel make issue, I guess I understand what you mentioned but I'm almost sure that it's not a dependency issue since the code successfully builds with parallel make on two other servers (Not docker of course). I'm getting suspicious on debian docker image now. Do you know how can I check if it is a bug with make on debian distro?

Comment: Most "official" images aren't. Even if somebody from the project uploaded it once, they probably forgot about it, because Docker doesn't solve any problems for people who write reliable software. You can check `apt-cache policy make` against [the latest changelogs](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/m/make-dfsg/) to see if there are any obvious bugfixes that your version is missing ... or you can inspect the rules (or run `make` with `-d`, or try with `-j` and no number) to see if it's a flaw in your Makefile.